# Reading first line of data from a text file

Tags: python, pandas

I’d like to read a text file as csv, but the beginning of the file is just plain text (the tab separated values start somewhere around line 20).
Because that file may be updated in the future, I’d like pandas to start reading the file at the correct row automatically (currently I obviously obtain a parser error).
Is there a way to configure the reading so that it finds how many rows to skip at the beginning of the file? (Maybe by fixing the number of columns?)
Thanks!

Edit: here below is the beginning of the text file. As can be seen, the 30 first rows aren't tab separated. For the moment, I just skip them with a fixed value, but I fear the file might be updated and that number might change

```
#
# Unihan_IRGSources.txt
# Date: 2021-08-06 16:32:36 GMT [JHJ]
# Unicode version: 14.0.0
#
# Unicode Character Database
# © 2021 Unicode®, Inc.
# Unicode and the Unicode Logo are registered trademarks of Unicode, Inc. in the U.S. and other countries.
# For terms of use, see http://www.unicode.org/terms_of_use.html
# For documentation, see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/
#
# This file contains data on the following fields from the Unihan database:
#   kCompatibilityVariant
#   kIICore
#   kIRG_GSource
#   kIRG_HSource
#   kIRG_JSource
#   kIRG_KPSource
#   kIRG_KSource
#   kIRG_MSource
#   kIRG_SSource
#   kIRG_TSource
#   kIRG_UKSource
#   kIRG_USource
#   kIRG_VSource
#   kRSUnicode
#   kTotalStrokes
#
# For details on the file format, see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/
#
U+3400  kIRG_GSource    GKX-0078.01
U+3400  kIRG_JSource    JA-2121
U+3400  kIRG_TSource    T6-222C
U+3400  kRSUnicode  1.4
U+3400  kTotalStrokes   5
U+3401  kIRG_GSource    G5-3024
U+3401  kIRG_KSource    K3-2121
U+3401  kIRG_TSource    T4-2224
U+3401  kRSUnicode  1.5
U+3401  kTotalStrokes   6
U+3402  kIRG_JSource    JA3-2E23
U+3402  kRSUnicode  1.5
U+3402  kTotalStrokes   6
U+3403  kIRG_KSource    K3-2122
U+3403  kRSUnicode  2.2
U+3403  kTotalStrokes   3
U+3404  kIRG_GSource    GKX-0079.02
U+3404  kIRG_JSource    JA-2123
U+3404  kIRG_TSource    T6-2130
U+3404  kRSUnicode  2.2
U+3404  kTotalStrokes   3
U+3405  kIRG_GSource    GKX-0081.18
U+3405  kIRG_JSource    JA-2124
U+3405  kIRG_TSource    T6-2123
U+3405  kRSUnicode  4.1
U+3405  kTotalStrokes   2
```

Comment: Could you please ade more detail about your txt file?

Comment: You want to skip the plain text part right?

Comment: Yes I'd like to skip the rows that aren't tab separated data. The lines actually start with a '#'. I added the first 50 lines or so to properly show the data, my first line of interest starts with 'U+3400'.

Answer (score 0):

If only the rows with tabs are valid, then this will work:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(line.strip().split('\t') for line in f if '\t' in line)
```

Comment: That might work, but since I have around 500 000 lines, I'd prefer to use pandas to do the data cleaning (if there's a way to avoid a loop going through each line).

Comment: See the duplicate question link~